# Android - Classes.Dex Double

Tags: android, apk, dex

Why my APK generated two classes.dex? I've build APK twice with different ID before. How to remove one of this?

[image]

Comment: this depends on the number of methods you have in the apk. If this is greater than 65k then there will be more than one dex file. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: before i build it with different id, it just generate one classes.dex sir, and i don't add  or edit anything. this is make me confusing sir :(

Answer (score 1):

You probably have accidentally disabled the minification of your code. Check for the `minifyEnabled: true` option.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: I have the same issue. I added the minifyEnabled option in build file ,but still the apk analyzer shows claases2.dex file.When I analyzed the apk some hours before, it was not showing the classe2.dex file and so the apk size was also less. Since then I have not edited my project ,but I'm not able to get why apk size is increased ? Can you please help me

Comment: How are you building your APK? Are you building the debug or release build?

Comment: I'm building release apk

Comment: thanks i was building my apk as an debug version ! so in the release version the size was better =)